# Consul template is not restarting nginx windows

Tags: nginx, consul, consul-template

I am using consul template v0.19.0 for ***windows***, for rendering nginx config.

The nginx config Is rendering fine by the consul template but It is not restarting the nginx.

This is the command I am using.

Consul- template   -consul-address="xx"  - template="in:out:{{pathfornginx}}\nginx.exe -s reload" .

Where "in" is the ctmpl path and "out" is the final nginx config path..

I have tried with different path format but no luck.

Could anyone drop some input on this.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to create a `config.json` file which will contain the path to the `ctmpl` file, and the command itself? 
You would need to use the -config flag instead of -template

If you want an example for the `config.json` I can provide you one.. I'm using similar setup and it works fine for me

Provide me a better solution?